# Search not showing all results

Tags: php, functions, pagination, search

**EDIT:** So I've done some troubleshooting and it seems my theme isn't showing woocommerce search results. The 2017 theme does so I am trying to figure out what my theme is missing. I suspect something in the `functions.php` file. It's something I'm leaving out, not something I've included that's interfering, because I deleted all my code out of the functions file line by line and nothing changed.

I have some custom code I have used elsewhere without any trouble. I tried just copying it over to my new theme and for some reason, its not working. The search results show 1-10 of 54 but the first page only shows four results. The rest of the pages show nothing. I can't figure what I could be doing wrong.

In `functions.php`:

```
function wpse_106121_posts_count( $wp_query = null ) {
if ( ! $wp_query )
    global $wp_query;

    $posts = min( ( int ) $wp_query->get( 'posts_per_page' ), $wp_query->found_posts );
    $paged = max( ( int ) $wp_query->get( 'paged' ), 1 );
    $count = ( $paged - 1 ) * $posts;

    printf(
       '%d - %d of %d',
        $count + 1,
        $count + $wp_query->post_count,
        $wp_query->found_posts
    );
}
```

In `search.php`:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
    <p><?php wpse_106121_posts_count() ?></p>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
    if ( '' !== get_post()->post_content ) : ?> 

        <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
            <p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read More</a></p>
            <hr class="divider">
    <?php endif; endwhile; else : ?>
    <p>No posts found.</p>

<?php endif; ?>
<div class="navigation"><?php
global $wp_query;

$big = 99999;
$translated = __( '', 'themename' );

echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
    'next_text' => __('NEXT >'),
    'prev_text' => __('< PREV'),
) );
?></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had an extra if statement in my `search.php` file that was filtering out content that didn't contain a proper excerpt.